# What kind of classes can be exetended by interfaces? What are the rules?

Tags: java, class, interface, extends

What kind of  classes can be extended by interfaces? What are the rules?

All the Java programmers I know think that interfaces cannot extend classes but

`java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`:

```
public interface ExecutorService extends Executor { //...
```

`java.util.concurrent.Executor`:

```
public class Executors { //...
```

So, it looks like some interfaces can extend some classes. What are the rules? I only noticed that `java.util.concurrent.Executor` has static members only and a private constructor. Can somebody explain the rules and the purpose? Thanks.

Comment: You should double-check your assumptions here... and re-read your own post's code.

Comment: `Executor` and `Executors` are different

Comment: Because Java doesn't allow static methods in interfaces (though this is apparently changing in Java 8), in many important interfaces there will be a singular interface and a class consisting entirely of static utility functions (with a private constructor) named with the plural. Compare Executor (the interface)/Executors (the method class), Collection (the interface)/Collections (the method class), etc, and also see Effective Java item 1.

Comment: @Dave Newton  Thanks a lot! You have saved me from going insane )) I have read the following in "Java How to program" ( Paul Deitel, Ninth edition, p.1051) "The **ExecutorService interface** (of package java.util.concurrent) _extends_ **Executor** and declares various methods for managing the life cicle of an **Executor**. I could not believe my eyes and looked into the code to double check it. It looks like I should've triple checked it (( Shame on me! )) Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

**Interface** can *only extend another interface* and *not a class*.

Since interfaces have no actual implementation of any logic (this is not possible in Java), there is no fear of possible collisions if some interfaces have the same method signatures.

Answer (score 1):

[`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) is an interface and not a class, unless Javadoc is mistaken or I misread your post. So there is not any problem with another interface extend it.

Answer (score 0):

Every single method declared in an interface will have to be implemented in the sub-classes.

A class can implement multiple interfaces and it can not be private.

A class that implements an interface must provide an implementation of all the method of that 
interface. as far as doing it the other way around as

@darijan says "Interface can only extend another interface and not a class......."